Unable to create Parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose Parquet type is optional binary
I am getting the following error when trying to read a parquet file using PySpark dataframe and writing it back to bigquery.
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: Unable to create Parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose Parquet type is optional binary

The dataframe schema shown after reading the ADLS parquet file is as below:
------------------------
|-- event_timestamp_local: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- event_timestamp_eu: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- event_timestamp_us: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- event_timestamp_asia: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- event_timestamp_africa: timestamp (nullable = true)
------------------------

The destination BQ schema is auto created by spark session after reading the above schema and the problem start happening from there.
I checked the parquet schema and found there is a 'timestamp' field. Is there any way to fix this error while keeping the same datatype in destination e.g: bq.

Not enough info. Post schema of original dataframe that you read and the DDL of target table. Also if it's some specific rows/values that cause this then would be good to include those values here.

@Kashyap: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question with the post schema of the df. The target table schema (i.e: BQ schema) is auto created by the spark session after reading the df schema. During the debug, I found that the issue is coming whenever the df schema is trying to convert to BQ schema in the spark session; specfically for the 'timestamp' field.

Using the configuration .config("spark.sql.parquet.timestampNTZ.enabled", "true") will help you.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.timestampNTZ.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

Because In Spark, the timestampNTZ type refers to "timestamp without timezone," & this will cause the ERROR:

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: Unable to create Parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose Parquet type is optional binary

when reading or writing Parquet files because of how timestamps are handled between systems.
When this configuration is enabled, Spark will handle timestamp fields in a way that avoids discrepancies between how the Parquet format stores timestamps and how they need to be read or written in PySpark.
This can prevent the error that occurs due to a mismatch in how Parquet interprets and stores timestamp data types compared to BigQuery.
Reference: Spark ignores parameter spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat

This is really helpful information. Will give it a try and upvote it.
